# Packages or functions for summarizing matrix in R that works similarly as dplyr?

Tags: r, performance

I am running a very big simulation with 10,000 loops and to achieve better performance I have transformed the codes to generate matrix outputs, rather than data frame. It runs faster. However for each loop I need to summarize the outputs. For example, for below matrix,

```
mtx <- matrix(data = c(rep(c(1, 2), each = 6),
                       rep(c(3, 5, 7), each = 4),
                       rnorm(0, 1, n = 12)),
          ncol = 3)
colnames(mtx) <- c("A", "B", "Value")
```

I want to summarize the number of observations in each `A` and `B` group, and calculate the mean values of `Value`, like the way that you could do with `group_by()` and `summarize()` in dplyr, if it's a data frame:

```
mtx %>% group_by(A, B) %>% summarize(N = n(), MEAN = mean(Value))
```

Are there any functions/packages to do this directly on matrix, without transforming it into data frame? Because the simulation is too big, collecting all the raw outputs and summarizing after the `for` loop is not an option.

Comment: Your requested output is not clear Do you want to group by A and separately group by B? Or do you want to group on A-B pairs?

Comment: @G5W, by A-B pairs. I edited the question by providing an example using `dplyr` to the desired output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate` directly on a matrix.

```
aggregate(Value ~ A + B, data=mtx, mean)
  A B      Value
1 1 3 -0.2282783
2 1 5  0.5021404
3 2 5 -0.1693665
4 2 7  0.5118390
```

Comment: Thank you! Apart from writing another aggregate function, is it possible that the number of rows could also be generated together with the mean value?

Comment: @XintingWANG  The number of rows should be the same for all columns. I would just use `nrow(mtx)`

Answer (score 1):

An option with `tapply`

```
tapply(mtx[, 'Value'], list(mtx[, 'A'], mtx[, 'B']), FUN = mean)
```